# Making a drawing with java fx of a function

Tags: javafx

I have a quick question
I have to draw on JavaFx using SceneBuilder the following drawing of the function
y=100+20*sin(x) where x is in the limit -90 deg. - 180 deg.
I think of using quadcurve, but really dont know what to do with the degrees.
thanks in advance with the advices

Comment: See also the blog post: [parsing an arithmetic expression using the shunting-yard algorithm and drawing with javafx](http://speedysoft.blogspot.com/2015/08/parsing-arithmetic-expression-using.html)

Comment: I've already seen these comments, but I still have no idea how to solve my problem. :D